# how to drop a categorical value from a data frame column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a data frame title `price_df`. and I would like to drop the rows that contain `'4wd'` from the column `drive-wheels`. I have tried `price_df2 = price_df.drop(index='4wd', axis=0)` and a few other variations after reading the docs pages in pandas, but I continue to get error codes. Could anyone direct me to the correct way to drop the rows that contain values `4wd` from the column and data frame? Below is the code I have ran before trying to drop the values:

```
# Cleaned up Dataset location
fileName = "https://library.startlearninglabs.uw.edu/DATASCI410/Datasets/Automobile%20price%20data%20_Raw_.csv"
# Import libraries
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy.random as nr
price_df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
round(price_df.head(),2) #getting an overview of that data
price_df.loc[:,'drive-wheels'].value_counts()
price_df2 = price_df.drop(index='4wd', axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
price_df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
mask = price_df["drive-wheels"] =="4wd"
price_df = price_df[~mask]
```

Comment: Thank yo, I didn't think to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.query` and back ticks for this column name with a hyphen:

```
price_df.query('`drive-wheels` != "4wd"')
```

Comment: I will try this and look into query. I have not used that before. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Get a subset of your data with this one-liner:

```
price_df2 = price_df[price_df.drive-wheels != '4wd']
```